dataproc template error with file dataproc_templates_distribution.egg
In order to import from JDBC to BigQuery based in dataproc templates, exactly using: jdbc_to_bigquery.py and bin/start.sh. You can check the official repo: Github GoogleCloudPlatform
Executing the following file.sh with the specific names for the variables ubuntu OS:
export GCP_PROJECT=<gcp-project-id>
export REGION=<region>
export GCS_STAGING_LOCATION=<gcs staging location>
export SUBNET=<subnet>
export JARS="<gcs_path_to_jdbc_jar_files>/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar,<gcs_path_to_jdbc_jar_files>/postgresql-42.2.6.jar,<gcs_path_to_jdbc_jar_files>/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar"

    ./bin/start.sh \
-- --template=JDBCTOBIGQUERY \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//1.1.1.1:1521/mydb?user=hr&password=password123" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.table="employees" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.partitioncolumn=id \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.lowerbound="11" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.upperbound="20" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.numpartitions="4" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.fetchsize="200" \
--jdbc.bigquery.input.sessioninitstatement="BEGIN DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('Dataproc Templates','JDBCTOBIGQUERY'); END;" \
--jdbc.bigquery.output.mode="overwrite" \
--jdbc.bigquery.output.dataset="bq-dataset" \
--jdbc.bigquery.output.table="bq-table" \
--jdbc.bigquery.temp.bucket.name="temp-bq-bucket-name"

When executing it runs until this error with the file dataproc_templates_distribution.egg:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:508: InformationOnly: Normalizing '0.5.0-beta' to '0.5.0b0'
  self.metadata.version = self._normalize_version(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying google_dataproc_templates.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/google_dataproc_templates-0.5.0b0-py3.12.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Will rename output .egg file from dist/google_dataproc_templates-0.5.0b0-py3.12.egg to dist/dataproc_templates_distribution.egg
JOB_TYPE is SERVERLESS, so will submit on serverless Spark
Triggering Spark Submit job
gcloud beta dataproc batches submit pyspark <confidential parameters>
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.batches.submit.pyspark) Failed to upload files ['./../dist/dataproc_templates_distribution.egg'] to 'gs://dataproc_test_jdbc_bq/dependencies': [./../dist/dataproc_templates_distribution.egg] not found or not accessible

Notes:

The file dist/dataproc_templates_distribution.egg is created locally.
In the bucket of GCS is created a folder: dependencies with a file main.py inside. The same one of the repo: dataproc-templates/python/main.py
With the command gsutil it's possible to upload the file.egg to GCS without problems

